# How to print the result of a method in android

Tags: android

I have a problem. I have a TextView, a TextEdit and a button:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final EditText TextEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextEdit);  
    final TextView mix =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mix);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.proces);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            // Perform action when clicking 



        }
```

and a method:

```
public String shuffle(String s) {  
            List<String> words = Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));  
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
            for (String w : words) {  
                 w = mixMe(w);  
                sb.append(w);  
                sb.append(" ");  
            }  
            return sb.toString().trim();  
        }
```

I want to take the text from the EditText field, apply to it the shuffle method and after that print it with setText, and all of this in the OnClik method, but I'm not sure how to do that. Can anyone help me please. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onClick method implement the following code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
String suffledString = shuffle(TextEdit.getText().toString());
TextEdit.setText(suffledString);
        }
```

Also if its not necessary remove the final keywords as it might cause a problem later yet not tested.
:)

Comment: You are warmly welcome Cristi, if you found this answer helpful I request you to mark it correct(By clicking on left "Tick Mark") to complete the question process.

:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final EditText TextEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextEdit);  
    final TextView mix =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mix);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.proces);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String s = shuffle(TextEdit.getText().toString());
            mix.setText(s);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

String s = shuffle(TextEdit.getText().toString());

TextEdit.setText(s);